# Histogram equalization on image

Tags: c, image-processing

I have this question? How to make histogram equalization on image in C? I wrote this code, but I don't get the correct result.

```
void histogram(unsigned char image_in [64][64],unsigned char image_out [64][64], unsigned long hist[256],unsigned long eHist[256],float cdf[256]) {
    #define lines 64
    #define columns 64

    int i,j;

    int pixels = lines*columns;

    // original histogram

    for (i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
        hist[i]=0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
              hist[image_in[i][j]]++;
        }
    }

    // Cumulative Distribution Function
    float cdfmax=256, cdfmin=1;

    for (i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
        cdf[i] = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
            cdf[i] += hist[i];
        }
    }

    // Equalized Histogram

    for (i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
        eHist[i] = ((cdf[i]-cdfmin)/((lines*columns)-cdfmin))*255;
    }

    // Final Image

    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        image_out[i][j] = cdf[image_in[i][j]]*255;
    }
}
}
```

That is my main function:

```
void main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("../lena_eye.raw","rb");
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
            image_in[i][j] = getc(fp);
        }   
    }

    fclose(fp);
    histogram(image_in, image_out, hist, eHist,cdf);
}
```

Тhe results I received can be seen in the images.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjhp9.png  -image_in
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/itDNE.png  -Hist
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/74Ulm.png  -eHist
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFwUw.png  -image_out

Comment: Тhanks for the amendments to the text, my English is not very good.

Answer (score 3):

This bit of code is wrong:

```
for (i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
    cdf[i] = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
        cdf[i] += hist[i];
    }
}
```

The inner loop changes the value of `i`, messing up the outer loop. What you wanted to write is something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    cdf[i] = 0;
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        cdf[i] += hist[j];
    }
}
```

...but it would be simpler to write:

```
cdf[0] = hist[0];
for (i = i; i < 256; i++) {
    cdf[i] = cdf[i-1] + hist[i];
}
```

Also, when you compute the histogram and the equalized histogram, you have loops starting at 1, they should start at 0.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake in the code and I share what I wrote.

```
 void Histogramm(unsigned char *image_in, unsigned char *image_out)
```

{

```
int i, j;
const unsigned long pixels = lines * columns;       
unsigned long cdf_min;
const unsigned char* limit = image_in + pixels;     
unsigned char* img;     
//    original histogram

for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    hist[i] = 0;
}


for (img = image_in; img < limit; img++)
{
    hist[*img]++;
}

//    Cumulative Distribution Function

unsigned long count = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    count += hist[i];
    cdf[i] = count;
}
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    if (cdf[i] != 0)
    {
        cdf_min = cdf[i];
        break;
    }
}
//                  Equalized Histogram

//eHist[i]=round((cdf[i]-cdf_min)/(pixels-cdf_min)*255)=round(k*(cdf[i]-cdf_min))
const double k = 255.0 / (pixels - cdf_min);

for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    eHist[i] = (unsigned long)(k*(cdf[i] - cdf_min));
}

//      Final Image

for (img = image_in; img < limit; img++)    
{
    *image_out = eHist[*img];
    image_out++;
}
```

}